# How to pass input arraylist on workmanager Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, io, android-workmanager

I have Problem how to passing input `arraylist` on `workmanager` input Android, because I tried to search only accept String, Integer. And, I have method to create input data like this.

```
private Data createInputData(ArrayList<String> imagepath){

        Data data = new Data.Builder()
                .put("imagepath",imagepath)//how to put arraylist on this part
                .build();
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: You can do `serialize/deserialize` [this how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172216/4390987)1

Comment: how i can do that when it's only string arraylist? just make  String s = gson.toJson(imagepath)?;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Data.Builder` class does support [adding a `String[]`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Data.Builder.html#putStringArray(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)). Therefore you just need to convert your `ArrayList<String>` into a `String[]`:

```
Data data = new Data.Builder()
    .putStringArray("imagepath", imagepath.toArray(new String[imagepath.size()]))
    .build();
return data;
```

Comment: and how to retreive data?like and normal array?

Comment: Yep, `getStringArray()`